# How do I return a boolean if a value is present in a list inside a list using java 8

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a List of objects, which contains a list of Strings. I want to return true if the 'names' list is not null and has size more than 1.

Consider the below code

```
class Obj {
  private List<String> names;
}

class Test {
  private List<Obj> objs;

  public boolean isPresent(String name) {
  //Loop through the list of lists
 }
}
```

Here I want to determine if 'names' is not null and has size more than 1 for any of the 'objs' objects. Is there a way we can do this using Streams in java 8?

Comment: Imo, your question doesn't seem to need to use the `name` argument.  Can you please clarify?

Comment: Please note that requests like yours here, that boil down to "please do my homework for me" aren't appreciated. There are many good tutorials on streams, so try yourself first. We help you with specific problems on your way, but there is no point in other people doing that initial work for you. You learn programming by programming.

Comment: My apologies people. I closed out my previous question and modified it a little bit over here. I'll delete this question and thanks for your advise.

Comment: I'm unable to delete the question, but I've flagged it for moderator intervention.

Comment: I apologize for this mess. It was unethical on my part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Preface

Your requirements are a bit unclear.  You're requirements could be read both as

- Return true if any names array has greater than 1, or
- Return true if all the names arrays are greater than 1

> Remember, there is a **names** array for each node in the **objs** list.

## Code

If you want to return true if any node in the names lists are greater than 1 then you would use the `boolean java.util.stream.Stream.anyMatch(Predicate<? super Obj> predicate)` method.

```
  public boolean isPresent() {
      return objs.stream().anyMatch( o -> o.getNames().size() > 1 );
 }
```

If you want to return true only in the case where all the nodes are greater than 1, and therefore not null, you would use the `boolean java.util.stream.Stream.allMatch(Predicate<? super Obj> predicate)` method

```
  public boolean isPresent() {
      return objs.stream().allMatch( o -> o.getNames().size() > 1 );
 }
```